# Does jQuery support crossbrowser hashchange event handling without additional plugins?

Tags: jquery, hash, event-handling

Does jQuery support `$(window).bind('hashchange')` without additional plugins?

If it does, what version of jQuery implements this operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery supports the `hashchange` event if and only if the browser supports it.

[**Browser compatibility**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onhashchange#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: Thanks, I just hoped that it was added to the jQuery core.

Comment: @Warlock, If every useful feature was in the core: 1) jQuery wasn't a small library. 2) it was a headache to maintain and develop.